# Hello i want to copy a character to a 2D array, but the second char wipes the first

Tags: c++, arrays

i am making a hangman game and the only thing i have left to do is copy the letters which have been inputted into a 2d array or 1d.

I have tried both and i am getting nowhere, using strcpy, strncpy, memcpy.

```
 char letterAttempt[26]={0};
                cin >> letterAttempt;

                char letterGuessed[26];

                memcpy (&letterGuessed,letterAttempt,sizeof(letterAttempt));

cin >> letterAttempt;

                char letterGuessed[26];

                strcpy (letterGuessed,letterAttempt);
```

I have been trying loads of variations, i have been through the debugger and the initial value goes there as soon as i enter the next it deletes the first and replaces it with the second.

I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Thank you, that has worked perfectly!

Comment: Now i just need to output each letter to the console. Back to it :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to store each guess in a different index in the array.

```
char letterAttempt;
char lettersGuessed[26];
int numberOfAttempts = 0;

// Loop round here    
    cin >> letterAttempt;

    // Check for duplicate guesses here?

    // This places the new guess in the numberOfAttempts-th place in the array ...
    lettersGuessed[numberOfAttempts] = letterAttempt;
    // and increments the number of guesses counter, ready for the next guess.
    numberOfAttempts++;

//  Check for correct answer, etc.
```